# How to copy a module

Tags: python, module, package

Let's assume I've got two modules `a.py` and `b.py`. `b`should be a copy of `a`.
Let's assume this is the content of `a`:

```
#a.py
class Original(object):
    name = 'original'
```

The most obvious way to duplicate `a` would be something like this:

```
#b.py
from a import *
```

But this does not really copy `a`, e.g.

```
>>>import a, b
>>>#this changes a.Original.name as well
>>>b.Original.name = 'FOOBAR'
>>>a.Original.name == 'FOOBAR'
True
```

So my question is How do I make a real copy?

Comment: Modules are loaded only once and class variables are created only once per class.

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use modules like one might typically use classes. Classes support multiple instances, but modules do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to update the `globals()` dictionary of `b.py` with the `deepcopy` of `globals()` from `a.py`. And as we can't copy a class object using `deepcopy`, So,  you'll create a new class using `type()` for all classes present inside `a.py`.

```
from copy import deepcopy
import types
import a

def class_c(c):
    #To create a copy of class object
    return type(c.__name__, c.__bases__, dict(c.__dict__))

filtered_a_dict = {k:v for k, v in a.__dict__.items()
                                   if not (k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__'))}

globals().update({k:deepcopy(v) if not isinstance(v, types.TypeType) 
                               else class_c(v) for k, v in filtered_a_dict.items()})

del a
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> import a, b
>>> b.Original.name = 'bar'
>>> a.Original.name == 'bar'
False
```

Note that we don't use modules for such purposes, a class is the right tool for such things.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

Given `a.py` as:

```
var = 123
```

You could do:

```
>>> import a
>>> b = a
>>> b.var = 1234
>>> a.var
1234
```

You can't, however, implement b as its own module.